# CKEditor 4 and ExtJS 6.7.0 integrate problem with pop-up window

Tags: javascript, extjs, ckeditor4.x

[img with example of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YI7dz.png)

Hello everyone,

I have a problem when I try to integrate CKEditor and ExtJS.
So, I have a window with a tree inside of it, when I click a tree item, it opens a grid in the tab panel which is centered. After that, if I double click the grid item it opens a window with a form, calling the method form.loadRecord().
All the datas is loaded fine in form including the one CKEditor.
But after I close my window which is the parent of form and try to open it again with double click in grid, it loads all the records in the form but not in the CKEditor, which extends from Ext.form.TextArea.
If I click again in the grid to open the same item again without closing the window, it loads the data in CKEditor.
I've created a CKEditor with a form Panel in Ext.getBody() for a test and it works fine, but when it is inside a window it doesn't work and I don't know what is happening.
I've checked with Sencha Support and they said that it's a problem of CKEditor.

Please help, already tried a lot of it and it does not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to override `setValue` method for your CKEditor component.

```
setValue: function (value) {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    if (this.editor) {
        this.editor.setData(value);
    }
},
```

It is difficult to assess the problem without any code. You could reproduce the problem in [fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't provide a fiddle because I can't upload the CKEditor package to the fiddle, or there's a way to do it?
I've already override it and doesn't work, the problem seems to be in pop-up window (Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{)};) on a button click in example.

Comment: Fork my [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2rcs) to show your example.

Comment: Oh, perfect! Your example shows a bug (same as mine)... try to change the "styles" or "normal", when you click it doesn't open anything... but if u create it inside a Ext.container.Viewport, instead of a window, it works... try it

Comment: The problem arises because the window has a high `z-index` - the problem is solved by setting the `z-index` higher than the window.  Look again [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2rcs)

Comment: Ok, it works fine now the problem of fullscreen... I'm trying to execute some tests atm.
Check this please
[new Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2rd5)

If you set layout to form it doesn't work...

Comment: wrap your ckeditor component to `container` `{
                    xtype: 'container',
                    fieldLabel: 'Test CKEditor',

                    height: 400,
                    width: '100%',
                    layout: 'fit',
                    items: {
                        xtype: 'ckeditor'
                        

                    }
                }`

Comment: Ok, perfect again... now the only problem I think is when I open a window with the configurations setted in fiddle, and call setData() method, it sets the value correctly, when I close the window and open again, the value previously setted doesn't show, sounds like closing the window doesn't destroy the CKEditor. I've
already called the destroy() method and stills the same... :(
For load records I'm calling this:
form.down('ckeditor').setValue(record[0].getData().texto);

Comment: Also, I've already tried this code without success...
for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
      CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
      CKEDITOR.instances[instance].destroy();
}

Comment: This will happen every time, because when you close the window, the whole DOM-tree is destroyed. You can try to solve this problem in one of the ways: 1) Write the result of the editor when `onChange` to the store. 2) use [closeAction](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html#cfg-closeAction) `method-hide` instead `method-destroy`.the first option is better

Comment: Ok, I'll try it tomorrow! Thanks!

Comment: Btw it's a little strange, If I destroy the window on close, when I open it again it shouldn't re-create it again?

Comment: Show in fiddle how you create window. Way is important

Comment: Dude... I'm really sad, in fiddle it works perfectly and I'm doing the same thing... [check updated fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ref)
The difference may be in the full layout run...
I have a main window (Ext.container.Viewport) with a button that opens a new window... this window is modal and layout border it does have a treePanel (west) inside of it, when I click a tree item, it opens a grid in the tab panel (center). After that, if I double click the grid item it opens a window with a form and the CKEditor inside of it...
I'll try to create exactly the same later

Comment: I've build [this](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ret)
The layout is identical, idk why in my project it's not working but in the fiddle it is

Comment: Hello! When I call CKEditor package from my local file, it doesn't work, but when I call CDN it works...
Already downloaded the last versions and stuff from CKEditor 4 site and nothing happens...

Comment: Package or just local file? What you see in console? Component not work, or what?

Comment: ckeditor local files (js, css, plugins, skins)
It doesn't show anything in console, no erros... I think the component works, it only has some problems showing sometimes... idk dude

Comment: Is there any other way to we discuss the problem ? StackOverflow recommends chat but I don't have a lvl required to it

Comment: Leave your email, telegram or skype

Comment: Telegram: @fndltm or phone number: +55 (31) 99267-7624

Comment: Hello. Could u help me again please?

Comment: Hello, did you solved this problem? Same issue. I call local CKEditor files and not works, but via CDN yes.

Comment: For me works:
in ckeditor4\plugins\dialog\styles\dialog.css change z-index from 10010; to 100100; and then in extjs component change param baseFloatZIndex from  190001 to 19500